# Does the GLM library for OpenGL not have a magnitude function?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm new to using the GLM library, but it appears it does not have a magnitude function. Is this correct? If so, what is the reasoning?

Comment: If you just need to compare magnitudes, you may want to use `glm::length2()` from the `gtx/norm.hpp` extension, as it avoids the expensive `sqrt`.  It is essentially equivalent to `glm::dot(v,v)`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`glm::length()`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00148.html#ga18d45e3d4c7705e67ccfabd99e521604):

> `genType::value_type glm::length( genType const & x )`
>
> Returns the length of x, i.e., sqrt(x * x).

And as @bcrist [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866948/does-the-glm-library-for-opengl-not-have-a-magnitude-function/19867151#comment29553518_19866948), [`glm::length2`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00211.html#ga6d326d62fd9b7f4f0a1b79e56492a7e4) from [`GLM_GTX_norm`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00211.html):

> `T glm::length2( vecType< T, P > const& x )`
>
> Returns the squared length of x.